# Python order list of lists in custom order based on first value of each list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to order a list of lists in a custom order, based on the first value of each list. The list of lists are my columns of a pivot_table dataframe (`cols = list(dfOverview.columns.values)`), where some columns are a list on itself.

Minimal working example (where I want the columns starting with `b` to move before `c`):

```
cols = ['2016', '2017', '2018', 
        ('a', '2016'), 
        ('a', '2017'), 
        ('a', '2018'), 
        ('c', '2016'), 
        ('c', '2017'), 
        ('c', '2018'), 
        ('b', '2016'), 
        ('b', '2017')]

sortOrder = {'2016': 0, '2017': 1, '2018': 2, 'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}

cols.sort(key=lambda val: sortOrder[val[0]])
```

This returns an error, and even though I tried and google'd a lot, I can't find a way to get this working. Desired result of cols:

```
['2016', '2017', '2018', 
 ('a', '2016'), 
 ('a', '2017'), 
 ('a', '2018'),  
 ('b', '2016'), 
 ('b', '2017'),
 ('c', '2016'), 
 ('c', '2017'), 
 ('c', '2018')]
```

To clarify, some context of  my problem: I pivoted a pandas data frame, resulting in a new data frame where columns could consist of a list of values (pivot table with multiple columns as argument). That makes it difficult to order, hence the above problem.

My dataframe is the result of the following function:

```
dfPivot = df.pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'], 
                         columns=['year','category'], 
                         values='price')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it's a bit hacky, but your approach is also hacky :D

```
>>> sorted(cols, key=lambda val: sortOrder[val[0]] if type(val) == tuple else sortOrder[val])

['2016', '2017', '2018', ('a', '2016'), ('a', '2017'), ('a', '2018'), ('b', '2016'), ('b', '2017'), ('c', '2016'), ('c', '2017'), ('c', '2018')]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from the fact you are using `key`. That is used to specify a value to be compared. You have a heterogenous list. You will end up comparing elements of different types. I would suggest you look at the `cpm` argument, which is a function to compare two elements. That way, you can be more precise with your sorting rule.

If i understood your problem correctly, you most likely want this sort:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, str):
        return cmp(a, b)
    elif isinstance(a, str) and isinstance(b, tuple):
        return cmp(a, b[1])
    elif isinstance(b, str) and isinstance(a, tuple):
        return cmp(a[1], b)
    elif isinstance(a, tuple) and isinstance(b, tuple):
        return cmp(a[1], b[1])
    else:
        print "Impossible"

    return 0

cols.sort(cmp=compare)
print cols
```

There are 4 cases to distinguish when looking at your list input. The `string string` case, the `string tuple`, `tuple string` and `tuple tuple` case.

We account for each of these cases and write the comparison rule for each.

The `cmp` function you see used in the `return` statements simply informs the relationship of the terms, with `-1` being `a < b`, `0` being `a = b` and `1` being `a > b`.

Please note that the comparison is `lexicographic` (string comparison). You might want to case the string to integers and compare those.

The result is this:

```
['2016', ('a', '2016'), ('c', '2016'), ('b', '2016'), '2017', ('a', '2017'), ('c', '2017'), ('b', '2017'), '2018', ('a', '2018'), ('c', '2018')]
```

If you replace accessing the second element of the tuple ( the year in your case ) with accessing the first, you will get this:

```
['2016', '2017', '2018', ('a', '2016'), ('a', '2017'), ('a', '2018'), ('b', '2016'), ('b', '2017'), ('c', '2016'), ('c', '2017'), ('c', '2018')]
```

You could add a flag to decide what item of the tuple the comparison should use.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. It sets sort `key` as the first element of a tuple or the variable itself otherwise.

```
cols = ['2016', '2017', '2018', 
        ('a', '2016'), 
        ('a', '2017'), 
        ('a', '2018'), 
        ('c', '2016'), 
        ('c', '2017'), 
        ('c', '2018'), 
        ('b', '2016'), 
        ('b', '2017')]

sorted(cols, key=lambda k: k[0] if isinstance(k, tuple) else k)

# ['2016',
#  '2017',
#  '2018',
#  ('a', '2016'),
#  ('a', '2017'),
#  ('a', '2018'),
#  ('b', '2016'),
#  ('b', '2017'),
#  ('c', '2016'),
#  ('c', '2017'),
#  ('c', '2018')]
```

Comment: thx! This sorts cols in a alphabetic order, right? How can I order it in a custom order (let's say c before a)?

Comment: you can use `reverse=True` parameter, although I'm not sure this is exactly what you want.

Comment: In the end, I want to reorder the columns of my pandas dataframe, but struggle since my dataframe is a pivot table where some column names are a list rather than a string.

Comment: So not just alphabetic or reverse-alphabetic

Comment: sorry, not sure what you are asking. if there's another order you need, feel free to update the question & I can update the answer.

Comment: I updated my question. Thx for your help, @Szabolcs solved it. I did not realize that my problem didn't have a typical answer, expected to be a more general problem.